# How to modify in place nested arrays of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have data in the format:

```
data={"services"=>[{"name"=>"foo","checks"=>["script1","script2"]},
{"name"=>"bar","checks"=>["script3"]}]}
```

I am trying to replace "checks" for each check to be "/bin/#{check}". The code I was playing with is

```
data["services"].map! {|svc|
  svc["checks"].map! {|check|
    check = "/bin/#{check}"
  }
}
```

But this code replaces the whole service hash instead of just one key, and I get:

```
{"services"=>[["/bin/script1", "/bin/script2"], ["/bin/script3"]]}
```

Can I use map! in deeply nested arrays of hashes of arrays of... ? Or how else can I do what I need?

Comment: Remove the outer exclamation point in `map!`. Really, this should be a `each` since you're not doing anything with these elements other than iterating. Also, `check = ...` is a little silly--we're interested in the return value of `map`, so just `"/bin/#{check}"` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! That worked.

Comment: Whenever you give an example, please show the *desired* result. From @ggorlen's comment I now see it must be `{"services"=>[{"name"=>"foo", "checks"=>["/bin/script1", "/bin/script2"]}, {"name"=>"bar", "checks"=>["/bin/script3"]}]}`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest avoiding changing `data` and just return a new hash:

```
new_data = data.each_with_object({}) do |(service, values), hash|
  hash[service] = values.map do |value|
    checks = value['checks'].map { |check| "/bin/#{check}" }
    value.merge('checks' => checks)
  end
end

=> {"services"=>[{"name"=>"foo", "checks"=>["/bin/script1", "/bin/script2"]}, {"name"=>"bar", "checks"=>["/bin/script3"]}]}
```